# Node.js Hosting: low bandwidth, high cpu

Tags: node.js, heroku, continuous-integration, web-hosting

I've been looking around for a Node.js hosting service that suits my (probably rather exceptional) needs. It's basically a web app for CMS editors to preview CMS pages. (The actual website is statically hosted.)

So it handles only **few requests**, but all page requests (*.html) trigger quite a series of actions, to simplify let's say it rebuilds a good part of the website.

What I need is a service that delivers **high performance** on **few occasions**. Also it should support continuous deployment, so that when we update something, the app stays always on. (also the simpler the better: I'm a frontend developer, not a dev ops).

I've tried Google Cloud: painfully slow update mechanism, rather complex, but stable and fast, but only if you pay a lot.

Heroku is very simple, but their plans are for standard web apps, focusing on many requests, high bandwidth etc. Still, the $250 plan is rather ok in terms of performance. But again: pricey.

Jelastic would offer this flexible vertical scaling. But it's hard to do Continuous deployment and I have not yet figured out how to update an app without interruption of service.

I also though about renting a virtual private server, but again I would not know how to provide continuous delivery. Also, I'd rather have a dedicated service.

It feels like there must be a simple service that I've just missed. I'm grateful for any help or hints!

Comment: For you I recommend VPS.  Install Ubuntu, then with `snap` install kubernetes - https://microk8s.io. And you have continuous delivery. If you use gitlab, it has kubernetes auto-devopts. Just create Dockerfile and push to git- it will be auto deployed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KiraLT – this might seem simple to you, but it's rather horrific to me to set something like that up and keep running. I'm searching for something easier. I love a service like Heroku, also the pricing is fine, just not for my use case. I'd pay for bandwidth and cpu time I'd never use.

I imagine something like Heroku, but I'd only pay for actual usage: cpu time and bandwidth. Right now I always have to "reserve cpu" and most of the time it's just running in idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have finally found an answer to my search: [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run)**

You'll only pay by usage, and it still offers very good performance. For my scenario it decreases cost by a crazy factor: we'll pay less than 1% of the previous solution (driven by Google App Engine).

I've also tried AWS Lambda, but I had many issues with the rather extensive node app (like dynamic requires).